# number_format() gera erro somente no return

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Dentro da tabela `orders`, eu tenho um campo `valor` definido como `decimal(10,2)`.

No arquivo `Order.php`, criei um método para formatar o valor:

```
public function getValorAttribute($valor)
{
    Log::debug($valor); // retorna 2423.42
    Log::debug(number_format($valor, 2, ',', '.')); // retorna 2.423,42
    return $this->attributes['valor'] = number_format($valor, 2, ',', '.'); // retorna erro
}
```

O problema é que o return está gerando o erro abaixo, enquanto o segundo `debug()` retorna o valor formatado:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido. Fiz uma confusão entre Accessors e Mutators. A versão final ficou assim:

```
public function getValorAttribute($value)
{
    $format = number_format($value, 2, ',', '.');
    return $format;
}
```

Mais info em https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators